# How to Edit Data From a File (Notepad)?

Tags: fstream

I am creating a Program that can Write and Read Data from a file, but i don't know how to start it, im new to c++,

for example, this is the Data:

Last Name: Pangan
First Name: Jomark
Middle Name: Razon
Age: 20
Employee ID: 2015000722

How can i Edit the Last Name from Pangan to Panganiban?

Comment: The question is not clear. Do you want to implement an editor like notepad? or want to implement a program which stores and reads data from a specified file.

Comment: Yes, i have a data in notepad,  i have a struct called Records and it has members like EmployeeID, Last Name, First Name, And Age, now what I want to do is for example, if i searched Employee ID : 1 , this Data will show:

Employee ID: 1   , Last Name: Pangan  , First Name : Jomark and so on, and then to Edit that block of Information